# babel-loader compiles files from excluded paths

Tags: webpack, babeljs

What I am doing wrong if I keep getting Babel-specilific errors from files of ignored paths while building Webpack bundle?

My error is always like this:

```
Module build failed: 
ReferenceError: [BABEL] 
/Users/benjamin/Code/Bounce/bounce-new/node_modules/section-iterator/dist/sectionIterator.js: 
Using removed Babel 5 option: 
/Users/benjamin/Code/Bounce/bounce-new/node_modules/section-iterator/.babelrc.stage 
- Check out the corresponding stage-x presets http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets
```

Notice `node_module` directory. It seems like Babel tries to compile code from external modules with this module's `.babelrc` config. It is definitely not what I expect, since I ignore babel-loading files from `node_modules` path:

```
loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: '/node_modules/',
    include: __dirname,
    query: {
      presets: ['react-hmre'],
      ignore: '/node_modules/' // even tried this
    }
  }
]
```

Please, advise me, where is my error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing exclude: /node_modules/ instead of exclude: '/node_modules/',

Comment: Great, thank you! I totally forgot to use proper regex here.